# Get Substring - everything before and after certain characters

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to find the best possible way to get a value of each variable from the output string as below:

```
SUCCESS Post Policy Success INVOICE No. :: WS1704003404 || Policy No :: 
59203313 || App No. :: 123456724
```

This is the string output that we got and we want to get the value of

```
WS1704003404
59203313
123456724
```

Comment: You need to find a pattern here. Does WS1704003404 and subsequent values always start with WS? Is it always Policy No., Invoice No., and App No.? RegExp would do it I'm sure. what have you tried?

Comment: What is your metric for "best possible way"?

Comment: How is the output "everything before and after certain characters"? It appears to be *nothing* before and *nothing* after certain characters, which is the opposite of the title of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regular expressions, e.g:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = " SUCCESS Post Policy Success INVOICE No. :: WS1704003404 || Policy No :: 59203313 || App No. :: 123456724 ";

        var pattern = @"::\s*(\w+)\s*";

        var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

        foreach (Match match in matches)
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);

    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Split` and `Substring` function to get the result that you want. first you Split that string with "||" as delimiter, then substring that string, and just take whatever after word "::"

```
string Input = "SUCCESS Post Policy Success INVOICE No. :: WS1704003404 || Policy No :: 59203313 || App No. :: 123456724 ";
var result = Input.Split(new[] { "||" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
            .Select(x => x.Substring(x.IndexOf("::") + 3));
```

Result :

```
WS1704003404
59203313
123456724
```